# Something wrong cycle with an array

Tags: java

```
package masivi;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Masivi {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    int atzimes[][]={{50,60,55,67,73},
                     {62,65,71,70,81},
                     {72,66,77,80,69}};

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
   int Y = 0;
       int D = 0;    
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Ievadiet skaitli kuru velaties parbaudit:");
     int x = scan.nextInt();

     while (Y<16){
     if (atzimes[a][b] == x) System.out.println("Skaitlis "+x+" atrodas saja masiva.");
     Y=Y+1;
     if (atzimes[a][b] == x) break;
     b=b+1;
     if (b==4) a=a+1;
     if (b==4) b=0;
      if (a==2) ;

}
  if (atzimes[a][b] == x) System.out.println("" );
  else System.out.println("Skaitlis "+x+" neatrodas masiva." );

    }
}
```

When I check the last value (69) it goes out of bounds and I don't know why. I've tried changing the value at which the loop ends but it doesnt help I'm currently out of ideas.It ask for value of x and checks if is in the array.

Comment: What does your code do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redo your loop with nested for loops.  Nested for loops look neater and allow for you to work through the code. You won't have as many mistakes either.

```
for(int i=0; i<6;i++){  
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++){   
      atzimes[i][j];  //do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: You also might want to combine `if` statements. ie instead of repeating `if (b==4)` just do  `if (b==4) { a=a+1; b = 0; }`

Comment: Completely agree on that one.  Also `b++;` and `Y++;` will clean up the clutter.

Comment: Yep - FYI op `a++;` is the same thing as `a = a + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset `a` in the same way you do `b` when you reach the end of arrat bounds.

Change

```
  if (a==2) ;
```

to

```
  if (a==2) a=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays begin at index zero. `atzimes` has dimensions of [3][5] so the last element of the array (69) is at index [2][4]. Anything beyond that is out of bounds. Your code can increment a beyond 2 so it can cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Also, you might want to use a better program structure. It is very complex to debug a program like that. use nested for or while loops instead of that `while (Y<16)` - it'll make it much easier to debug.